# How find this $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k a_k^2$

Tags: polynomials, summation

Compute $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k a_k^2$ where $a_k$ are the coefficients in the expansion
$$(1- \sqrt 2 x +x^2)^n =\sum_{k=0}^{2n} a_k x^k$$

and This problem is IMO LongList 1988 http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2010150&sid=e1e93cee3b0b94a08914bb228542c82a#p2010150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

The form of the polynomial $p(x)= 1-\sqrt 2 x +x^2$ appeals to use its conjugate polynomial 
$q(x)= 1-\sqrt 2 x +x^2$. Such the usage can be a evaluation of roots and applying Vieta’s formulas, or dealing with a recurrent sequence.  But to chose the relevant way to solve the problem we should begin from the end (as recommended George Polya). So, we can see that 
the asked sum $S=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k a_k^2$ is equal to the coefficient at $x^0$ of the “polynomial” $p^n(x)p^n(-1/x)$. It rests to find it. We have

$$p^n(x)p^n(-1/x)=(p(x)p(-1/x))^n=$$ $$((1-\sqrt 2 x +x^2)(1/x^2+\sqrt 2/x +1))^n=$$ $$
((1/x^2)(1-\sqrt 2 x +x^2)(1+\sqrt 2x +x^2))^n=$$ $$((1/x^2)((1+x^2)^2-(\sqrt 2x)^2))^n=(x^2+1/x^2)^n.$$

So we see that $S=0$ provided $n$ is odd and $S={n \choose n/2}$ provided $n$ is even.